# Mod-rewrite 301 link wont redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Can some one tell me the 301 rewrite rule for this link please, I need to remove the toolrepairshop and the %2520

```
toolrepairshop-blog?mywebsite_blog_tag=tool%2520repair%2520shop
```

to

```
blog?mywebsite_blog_tag=tool-repair-shop
```

Sorry this needed to be redirected to

blog?mywebsite_blog_tag=tool%20repair%20shop

am sure the blog module is automatically adding the %20

Comment: You can do it by this way also.
RewriteRule ^toolrepairshop-blog?mywebsite_blog_tag=(.*)$ /blog?mywebsite_blog_tag=$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the followin redirect in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  /toolrepairshop-blog\?mywebsite_blog_tag=tool%2520repair%2520shop [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog?mywebsite_blog_tag=tool-repair-shop [NC,L,R=301,NE]
```